# Help with inline IIF ampscript statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, web-analytics-connector

I am trying to write an inline IFF statement for use in our Web Analytics Connector parameter string. Currently I have the following:

```
...&utm_content=%%=iif(IndexOf("%%linkname%%","http")>0,"unknownlink", "%%linkname%%")=%%
```

When an explicit Link Name has not been set for a link, the full http.... web address renders in the url as the utm_content value. This breaks our website. So the point of the IFF is to check if %%linkname%% is actually a http web address, then just put "unknownlink" instead.

I have done a lot of testing on this and it seems to work well.

However, now I am trying to also handle links that are an ampscript function. For example, if using a RedirectTo function, then the utm_content paramter value renders in the url as literally %%=RedirectTo(......)=%% which is no good.

So I want to add in an OR to handle both "http" and "%%=" values. But I can't figure out how to do an inline IFF OR statement. I have tried the following:

```
 ...&utm_content=%%=iif((IndexOf("%%linkname%%","http")>0 OR IndexOf("%%linkname%%,"%%=")>0),"unknownlink", "%%linkname%%")=%%
```

and

```
...&utm_content=%%=iif(or(IndexOf("%%linkname%%","http")>0,IndexOf("%%linkname%%,"%%=")>0),"unknownlink", "%%linkname%%")=%%
```

Neither work. Anyone know how to do this or if it's possible?

---

*Adding some additional info for context*

What we are trying to do is be able to track performance of dynamic content in GA. So we are using utm_content as a url analytics parameter and then trying to populate this with the Tracking Alias (%%linkname%%) for GA to use.

However, we would only input a tracking alias value when required (eg: on dynamic content) and leave all other links blank. In this scenario, all other links would result in the entire url of said link being rendered in the resulting url as a parameter value. This breaks out website.

So I am trying to solve for a way to prevent this. Over many long discussions with Salesforce, there didn't seem any known way to do this. Their only suggestion was to put ampscript (like what I am trying to do) in the WAC string to check if a fully formed url was being set as %%linkname%% and overriding this with a simple text string. I did not want to do this initially since in the event any issues arose only support could change the WAC string. Now that admins can edit the WAC string, I am open to putting ampscript in there.

Comment: for the last line: there is no OR() function in AMPScript. Atleast not in the function reference.

Comment: Another comment: By the time you executed this script the %%linkname%% might already be executed, that is why you maybe won't find this succeding

Comment: Another thing: %%linkname%% will not use the url of the link but the tracking alias. Its not  good idea to have the tracking alias as an URL but rather something like a position or content description.

Comment: Thanks. You can use OR in ampscript, even though I can't find it documented anywhere. It does work correctly with my current version (first code snippet) so all good there. Finally, the issue with personalisation string %%linkname%% is that if no Tracking Alias value has been set then it defaults to the full url, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Sorry re being able to use OR I meant you can use it but I think you are right in that there is no actual OR() function.

Answer (score 3):

As [**@Johannes**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/52639/johannes-schapdick) suggested, `linkname` is substituted at the same time the AMPscript is evaluated.

I'd recommend utilizing [**AttributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue), which will return an empty string if there the substitution string that doesn't exist.

```
%%=iif(IndexOf(AttributeValue("linkName"),"http") > 0 OR empty(AttributeValue("linkName")), "unknownlink", AttributeValue("linkName"))=%%
```

Comment: This would also result in changing links that include http somewhere (for example parameters, accidental hashes, ...). Wouldn't it be better to search for "http" only at the start of the linkName?

Comment: Thanks Adam. That doesn't work unfortunately as now even if there is a Tracking Alias value, I still get "unknownlink" as a result. I recall when speaking to SF that the %%linkname%% personalisation string behaves differently in that it does not execute at send time but rather when a link is clicked. Maybe that is why?

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: I am updating the WAC String (since we can do that ourselves now) and then sending a test email I have setup with some dynamic content, some RedirectTo links, etc.

Comment: RedirectTo links end up like this in the url: &utm_content=%%%3dRedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(000))%3d%% which breaks our site

Comment: its because the logic you had in your example is outputting 'unknownlink' if it contains 'http' - which Adam copied. You need to change it to `%%=iif(IndexOf(AttributeValue("linkName"),"http") > 0, AttributeValue("linkName"), "unknownlink")=%%` and that should correctly output it.